# Execute Java script via cmd from R

Tags: r, cmd, prompt, drive

I use Windows and want to execute a Java script. However, the Java script is on drive D:, not C:. With the command

`start /D "D:\\project\\Trimmomatic" java -jar trimmomatic.jar PE -phred64 -threads 16 x1.fastq x2.fastq clipped_paired_x1.fastq clipped_unpaired_x2.fastq clipped_paired_x2.fastq clipped_unpaired_x1.fastq LEADING:3 TRAILING:3`

I can run trimmomatic.jar from C: in the prompt. However, if I wrap that line in R's `system()` command, and execute

`system('start /D "D:\\project\\Trimmomatic" java -jar trimmomatic.jar PE -phred64 -threads 16 x1.fastq x2.fastq clipped_paired_x1.fastq clipped_unpaired_x2.fastq clipped_paired_x2.fastq clipped_unpaired_x1.fastq LEADING:3 TRAILING:3')`

from R, it returns the bash error 127. Any ideas how to fix this or execute the jar file on D: in a different way?

Comment: have you tried the system function? Or just including this code in a separate bash script and running that through R? Or running R with something like opt parse and then running this java in same master script?

Comment: @cianius Edited the question, i.e. I executed the line directly from R

Comment: since you're on Windows, maybe try `shell()` instead of `system()`?

Comment: @Where'smytowel Uneblievable. That worked. Funny. Never encountered such problems with system and other tools ... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

@Where's my towel gave the answer. If you use `shell()` instead of `system()` it works!